# Show that E is open iff $E \cap bdE = \emptyset$

Tags: real-analysis

Show that E is open iff $E \cap bdE = \emptyset$
bd means boundary. that is what i have so far

proof: Given that $E$ is open then i will show $E \cap bdE \subseteq \emptyset$ and $\emptyset \subseteq E \cap bdE$.

let $x \in E \cap bdE$ that means $x \in E$ and $x \in bdE$ but E is open and $bdE$ is closed by definition those that mean their intersection is empty.

if $x \in \emptyset$ does that mean $x$ is in the intersection automatically.

how do i go about the converse.
thanks

Comment: Your argument doesn't work -- for exampl, $(0,2)$ is open and $[1,3]$ is closed, but their intersection is $[1,2)$ which is not empty!

Comment: i figure that much. i see

Comment: You need to look up the defintion of boundary of a set.

Answer (score 0):

$\text{bd}(E) := \overline{E} \setminus E^\circ$

$\Rightarrow$

If $E$ is open then $E = E^\circ$

$$\text{bd}(E) \cap E = \text{bd}(E) \cap E^\circ =
(\overline{E} \setminus E^\circ) \cap E^\circ=
\emptyset$$

---

$\Leftarrow$

$\text{bd}(E) \cap E = \emptyset$

Take a point

$p \in E \not\in E^\circ \Rightarrow p \in \overline{E}$

This implies $p$ is a boundary point of $E$, $\:p \in \text{bd}(E)$.

But since $p \in E$ this contradicts that $\text{bd}(E) \cap E = \emptyset$.

Hence, since $p$ was arbitrary there are no points $p \in E \not\in E^\circ$.

Thus $E$ is open.